# Can't push rails code to Heroku from Cloud9 because of sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to stark-reaches-8517.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/stark-reaches-8517.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com....
```

First I installed the latest `sqlite3`, but it didn't help. Then I tried to switch from `sqlite` to `postgresql`, but it didn't work out either (or I just missed something). Can somebody tell me how the gem file should look like before bundling? Btw. I am trying to follow Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, but it doesn't mention anything about this.

### Added:

I have the `rails_12factor` and `postgres` gems in the production group. `sqlite3` is in the development group so heroku should not attempt to install it.

Comment: How about message in your errors? [__Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.__](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the postgres gem in your `production` group.

Comment: postgres gem is in the production group. I tried to do it again from the beginning but still getting the error.

Comment: I edited the question and added your comment to @KyleSwartz answer since it is very pertinent.

Comment: Could you add your complete Gemfile to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you used postgresql did you have add a Procfile to your app with this line:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

I use the following in my gem file, in addition to postgres to deploy to heroku

```
#User the 'thin' server instead of the default webrick
gem 'thin'

#Use postgres and the Heroku rails gem for Heroku
group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Also, have you checked out the heroku help center? It jumps around a little bit, but goes into more detail about defing a Profile.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction

Comment: rails_12factor and postgres are in the production group; sqlite3  is in the development group so it shouldn't get in to heroku